# Does Web Api support two and multi dimensional arrays for serialization and parameter binding?

Tags: arrays, web-services, serialization, data-binding, asp.net-web-api

I know that web services with Web Api can handle all the serialization and parameter (or data) binding tasks automatically for one dimensional arrays.

For example, a model class like the following one can be converted to JSON/XML and bound to a parameter of type *Person* automatically by the web api framework:

```net
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double[] Notes { get; set; }  // 1-dim array
}
```

What if the model class includes a two or multi dimensional array, like the following one? Can Web Api also handle such arrays automatically, or does the user need to write some extra code for serialization and data binding?

```net
public class Person2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public double[,] NoteMatrix { get; set; }  // 2-dim array
}
```